# Mysql UPDATE based on lowest value in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

I've got the following Mysql structure:

- `jss_products`

  - `productID`
  - `price1`
- `jss_extrafields_values`

  - `exvalID`
  - `productID`
  - `extraFieldID`
- `jss_extrafields_prices`

  - `exvalID`
  - `price1`

Each product has a few extrafields. I'm interested in `extraFieldID = 1`

I wish to update all of the `price1` in `jss_extrafields_prices` using the value of `jss_products.price1`. I have the following query but it only updates the first entry per product in `jss_extrafields_price`, not all entries.

I'm trying to normalize the prices in `jss_extrafields_prices` so that for a product which has a price of `20.00`, each relevant entry in `jss_extrafields_prices` becomes `CURRENTPRICE - 20`.

Does that make sense? Here's what I have so far

```
UPDATE jss_extrafields_prices AS JEP
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT P.productID, P.price1 AS P1, EP.price1, EP.exvalID FROM jss_products AS P
    INNER JOIN jss_extrafields_values AS EV
    ON P.productID = EV.productID
    INNER JOIN jss_extrafields_prices AS EP
    ON EV.exvalID = EP.exvalID
    WHERE EV.extraFieldID = 1
    GROUP BY P.productID
    ORDER BY P.productID DESC, EP.price1 DESC
) AS X
ON JEP.exvalID = X.exvalID
SET JEP.price1 = JEP.price1 - X.P1
```

I would expect the inner query to return something like:
`productID = 1090`
`P1 = 20.8333333`
`price1 = 20.8333333`
`exvalID = 3236`

Knowing that `productID` of 1090 has 3 pricing options and its base price is `20.83333` I would then want to update every matching product in `jss_extrafields_prices` to be the current price minus the base price.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help andr.

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected result?

Comment: I've added some sample data for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping away some of the information that was previously classes as being too localized, this simplified to an UPDATE with an INNER JOIN:

```
UPDATE jss_extrafields_prices 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT P.productID, P.price1 AS baseprice, JEP.price1 AS optionprice, JEP.exvalID, (JEP.price1 - P.price1) AS adjustedprice FROM jss_products AS P
    INNER JOIN jss_extrafields_values AS JEV
    ON P.productID = JEV.productID
    INNER JOIN jss_extrafields_prices AS JEP
    ON JEV.exvalID = JEP.exvalID
    WHERE JEV.extraFieldID = 1
) AS X
ON jss_extrafields_prices.exvalID = X.exvalID
SET jss_extrafields_prices.price1 = X.adjustedprice
```